# Impossible to address a groovy file from Gradle script in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I have a large Gradle script including several Groovy classes. I want to separate these classes to different files so that they would be visible for the remaining Gradle task and each other.

The variants, proposed on SO for pure Gradle, without IntelliJ, won't work:

Putting a class into

```
|-buildSrc
|    |- src
|        |- main
|            |- groovy
|                |- GatewayFunctionBuilder.groovy
```

and calling them as :

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1'
}

task Xml2Java() { doLast{
    GatewayFunctionBuilder gatewayFB
```

, does not work, `cannot resolve symbol GatewayFunctionBuilder`.

Notice, the groovy files should not work as the part of the build, but as the parts of the Gradle scripts.

I had tried to put that buildSrc folder into the module, where the task lives, or into the root project (where it should be, according to https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/custom_tasks.html), nothing changes.

I have tried to remove mentioned `apply` and `dependencies` - nothing changes.

I had tried mark/unmark directory `groovy` as a `sources root` - nothing changes, except the color of directory and of the class file icons in the Project window.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is, as many times before - some unknown problems with IntelliJ or its Gradle plugin.

Its ***restart*** made the task see the groovy class in buildSrc. (The buildSrc really must be in the root.)